# How do I hide an HTML element before the page loads in conditional fields drupal module?

Tags: javascript, drupal, conditional-statements, field

I have lot fields in conditional fields module in drupal and shows or hides with module.

However, on the browser, the content loads visible for a second before disappearing, which is not what I want.

How do I set the hide the element before the page loads whilst keeping the ability to show hide it dynamically with a script or another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional fields should be adding CSS classes to those fields, which will hide them until the relevant javascript has fired.

Check you haven't written any styles which are causing them to be displayed before the javascript has run. (i.e. display:block).

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer !